# How to explicitly specify type of column in make_column in sqlite_orm?

Tags: c++, sqlite, orm

I want to use [sqlite_orm](https://github.com/fnc12/sqlite_orm) and I want to explicitly specify type of column when I declare table based on my classes.

So my question is how to explicitly specify type of column in make_column? for example how to explicitly specify one column in our class is blob type or is TEXT?

Comment: What type of field do you have?

Comment: As you can see in my question, my type is TEXT or blob or something other

Comment: I mean: what C++ type of field do you have?

Comment: thanks for replaying me :), I have long string (with ASCII text), big vector<uint8_t> (as blob), and something other

Comment: You need to make custom type bindings just like it is done in examples with enum bindings https://github.com/fnc12/sqlite_orm/blob/master/examples/enum_binding.cpp